# Fix :hover issues on iOS devices, universally with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, hover, touch

At the moment I'm having a following issue, when I first tap on something the :hover state gets triggered and I than need to tap second time in order to actually click an element. Fixes I found were targeting just some elements, and have been provided year or more ago. I thought maybe something recent has occurred, which allows to fix this issue universally? maybe get rid of all :hover rules in once, if user is on a touch device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that :hover is what's happening? Often the css rule will be on

```
:hover, :focus
```

or something like that. :hover shouldn't happen at all on a touch device, but :focus would occur once the link is touched. You could just break your hover and focus rules apart from each other. Alternatively, you could use modernizr to detect touch support and style against the classes it creates on the body element.

Comment: it is definitely hover, difference is that it is applied to a paragraph tag (long to explain, but that paragraph acts a an anchor tag) and when I click it I can see all :hover rules applied to it, but I have to click twice in order to activate it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something a bit closer to what your asking for. It will remove hover styles from your parsed CSS.

[iOS :hover fix](http://retrogamecrunch.com/tmp/hover-fix#)

```
// disable :hover on touch devices
// based on https://gist.github.com/4404503 
// via https://twitter.com/javan/status/284873379062890496
// + https://twitter.com/pennig/status/285790598642946048
// re http://retrogamecrunch.com/tmp/hover
if ('createTouch' in document)
{
    try
    {
        var ignore = /:hover/;
        for (var i=0; i<document.styleSheets.length; i++)
        {
            var sheet = document.styleSheets[i];
            for (var j=sheet.cssRules.length-1; j>=0; j--)
            {
                var rule = sheet.cssRules[j];
                if (rule.type === CSSRule.STYLE_RULE && ignore.test(rule.selectorText))
                {
                    sheet.deleteRule(j);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(e){}
}
```

Comment: @user2909035 Adding the linked code to the answer would have been a legitimate edit, but if you're adding your own code than it should be posted as a new answer (with a note giving credit to the answer you're expanding on) rather than an edit to an existing answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jarrod!

Your code works great, except for cases of compound CSS selectors.

I extended your code to work with compound selectors:

```
var disableCSSHoverSelectors = function (param_window) {
    'use strict';

    var css_style_rule_type, hover_expression, stylesheet_index, stylesheet, css_rules_index, css_rules, css_rule, parts, filtered_parts, parts_index, part;

    try {
        // Touch enabled?
        //
        if (('ontouchstart' in param_window) || ((param_window.DocumentTouch) && (param_window.document instanceof DocumentTouch))) {
            // Determine style rule type
            //
            css_style_rule_type = param_window.CSSRule.STYLE_RULE;

            // Define hover expression
            //
            hover_expression = /:hover/;

            // Iterate stylesheets
            //
            for (stylesheet_index = 0; stylesheet_index < param_window.document.styleSheets.length; stylesheet_index += 1) {
                stylesheet = param_window.document.styleSheets[stylesheet_index];

                // Iterate rules
                //
                css_rules = stylesheet.cssRules;
                if (css_rules === undefined) {
                    css_rules = stylesheet.rules;
                }
                for (css_rules_index = css_rules.length - 1; css_rules_index >= 0; css_rules_index -= 1) {
                    css_rule = css_rules[css_rules_index];

                    // Check rule type
                    //
                    if (css_rule.type === css_style_rule_type) {
                        // Expand compound selectors
                        //
                        if (css_rule.selectorText.indexOf(',') !== -1) {
                            parts = css_rule.selectorText.split(',');
                        } else {
                            parts = [ css_rule.selectorText ];
                        }

                        // Filter individual selectors
                        //
                        filtered_parts = [];
                        for (parts_index = 0; parts_index < parts.length; parts_index += 1) {
                            part = parts[parts_index];

                            if (!hover_expression.test(part)) {
                                filtered_parts.push(part);
                            }
                        }

                        // Update rule selectors or delete
                        //
                        if (filtered_parts.length > 0) {
                            css_rule.selectorText = filtered_parts.join(',');
                        } else {
                            stylesheet.deleteRule(css_rules_index);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (ignore) {
        // Not fatal
        //
    }
};
```